# Sort an Array of Objects angular typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

In TypeScript application i set array of objects and show it to user in my template

```
feedList: News[] =
  [
    { type: 1, slug: 'news', date: '2018/04/30', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},
    { type: 2, slug: 'post', date: '2018/04/20', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
    { type: 1, slug: 'news', date: '2018/04/28', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
    { type: 1, slug: 'news', date: '2016/04/28', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
    { type: 2, slug: 'post', date: '2018/03/28', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' }
  ];
```

I have a function of sorting

```
sortByType(feedList: News[]): void {
    feedList.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.type - b.type;
    });
  }
```

And I calling it in template

```
%button.btn{(click)="sortByType(this.feedList)"} Sort
```

But there is no changes and to errors. What I doing wrong?

If I use simply

```
[#objectarray#].sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.type - b.type;
        });
```

— it works

upd: all template

```
.feed
  %button.btn{(click)="sortByType(this.feedList)"}
    Sort by type
  .f-item{*ngFor: "let feedItem of feedList", class: "{{feedItem.slug}}"}
    .type
      {{feedItem.type}} {{feedItem.slug}}
    .date
      {{feedItem.date}}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your template? It looks like syntax error to me.

Comment: Yes, thanx! In haml i must to use `tar{key: value`, but i used `=`

Answer (score 3):

If the value is string

```
 data.sort((a, b) => a.status.localeCompare(b.status));
```

If the value is int

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.status===b.status?-1:0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I write a sort function by Typescript in Angular that sort an array of object based on property of list.

Assume we Have a List of Objects Like That:

```
Items: News[] =

      [
        { type: 1, slug: 'news', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},
        { type: 2, slug: 'post', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
        { type: 1, slug: 'news', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
        { type: 1, slug: 'news', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
        { type: 2, slug: 'post', title: 'Header New', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' }
      ];
```

My Function is Like That:

```
sort(array:any[],property:string,isNumber:boolean){
        if(isNumber){
            return array.sort((item1,item2)=> {
                return (item1[property] > item2[property]) ? 1 : -1;});
        }else{
            return array.sort((item1,item2)=> {
                return (item1[property].toLowerCase() > item2[property].toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1;});
        }
    }
```

- param 1 : is array that should be sort
- param 2 : is the property that sorting happens based on it
- param 3 : is the Boolean that determine param 2 is number or string

Answer (score 0):

in your template:

```
(click)="sortByType(feedList)"
```

in component:

```
sortByType(feedList: News[]): void {
    feedList.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.type - b.type;
    });
this.feedList = feedList  }
```

in your template where you want to show the sorted array put:

```
{{feedList|json}}
```

Comment: I found syntax error in template. Thanx for you answer